# How to order blog posts by no. of likes?

Tags: plugins, sort, blog

I am using a plugin called Kodex likes and it has a counter for how many likes a blog post got.

If I add sorting parameters to the URL using the ones already built in Wordpress like:

```
www.website.com/blog/?orderby=date&order=asc
www.website.com/blog/?orderby=title&order=desc
```

..it works! But when I try to use Kodex likes parameters (to show the most liked to least liked post) as in:

```
www.website.com/blog/?orderby=kodex_posts_likes&order=desc
```

..it doesn't work. I got this sort parameter from the posts overview dashboard in my WP Admin, so I thought it would also work if I use it on the actual webpage URL:

[image]

Developer did mention this in the plugin set

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'meta_key'  => 'kodex_post_likes_count',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
));
```

But I'm not sure how to translate that into the URL parameters. How do I get this to work? Is there anything missing?

Comment: try this www.website.com/blog/?meta_key=kodex_posts_likes&orderby=meta_value_num&order=desc

Comment: You'd better ask the plugin author.

Comment: @BikashWaiba he did mention this in the settings:

$custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
 'post_type' => array('post'),
 'meta_key'  => 'kodex_post_likes_count',
 'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
 'order'     => 'DESC'
));

not sure how to translate that into the URL variables?

Comment: I tried: www.website.com/blog/?meta_key=kodex_post_likes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC  .. but it didn't work..